# Excel EOMONTH function on range using TRANSPOSE

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I noticed that if I try to use EOMONTH on more than one cell at a time on for instance:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 |
| 2 | 1/2/2022 |
| 3 | 1/3/2022 |
| 4 | 1/4/2022 |
| 5 | 1/5/2022 |
| 6 | 1/6/2022 |
| 7 | 1/7/2022 |
| 8 | 1/8/2022 |
| 9 | 1/9/2022 |
| 10 | 1/10/2022 |
| 11 | 1/11/2022 |
| 12 | 1/12/2022 |
| 13 | 1/13/2022 |

If I use the following formula:
`=EOMONTH(A1:A13,0)`

I get a #VALUE! Error.

[image]

If I was to transpose the range (and transpose back to the original state) it works without errors:

`=EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(A1:A13)),0)`

[image]

Could someone explain this behaviour?

PS same goes for EDATE()

Comment: That is weird, I was expecting you to invoke `TRANSPOSE` after `EOMOTH` invocation, but the way you put it, the only difference is that instead of a range `EOMONTH` will have as input an array. For ranges (vertically or horizontally) doesn't work, but for arrays it works: `EOMONTH({1;2},0)`,  `EOMONTH({1,2},0)`. This behavior is not documented I would say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=EOMONTH(A1:A13,0)` is expecting a single date but it gets multiple dates so returns an error.

`=EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(A1:A13)),0)` works because the `TRANSPOSE` converts the range of data into an array first and it looks like `EOMONTH` can handle that so it outputs it as an array. It works the same if you use another function that converts the data to an array e.g. `=EOMONTH(UNIQUE(A1:A13),0)` also works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Still strange. Isn't a range an array?

Comment: Not really - a range is a location of data i.e. the cells of A1:A13, and `EOMONTH` does not know whether to evaluate A1, A2, A3... or A13. An array is a list of data so it'd be that `EOMONTH` with `UNIQUE` or `TRANSPOSE` has to evaluate only one thing and that is a list of data of '1/1/2022 1/2/2022 1/3/2022 (etc.)'.

Answer (score 6):

The unary plus operator (+) is also sufficient to coerce an array return:

`=EOMONTH(+A1:A13,0)`

Comment: Nice catch, that's way more convenient than transposing it twice

Comment: I was thinking about something similar: `=EOMONTH(1*A1:A13,0)` but the @JosWoolley approach takes one character less, :-)

Answer (score 1):

To coerce the range into an array, add a double negative (double unary) before the range.

```
=EOMONTH(--A1:A13,0)
```

The EOMONTH function results will then spill to match the array.

I tend to always use the double unary, as it has an advantage in other situations.
When Excel returns TRUE or FALSE values, it coerces them into to their numeric equivalents, 1 and 0.
This allows you to use functions like **COUNTIF** on the results.

[Bob Philips](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/515039-difference-between-range-and-array.html) described the difference between a range and array best, for me:

> A range is a set of contiguous cells or dis-contiguous areas within a
> spreadsheet."
>
> An array is a series of objects, such as an array of integers, an
> array of strings, or even an array of range objects.